# Pandas: remove empty strings from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe

```
id    m1    m2    m3
111   20    0     12
222   0     0     0
333   3     1     18
```

I need to get only

```
id    m1    m2    m3
111   20    0     12
333   3     1     18
```

I use

```
df.drop(axis=0, how='all')
```

But it returns me full dataframe.
How can I fix that?

Comment: @Bharathshetty it returns me None with `inplace=True`

Comment: I thought its dropna sorry. You can do that without using drop. Check if my answer helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing i.e

```
ndf = df[~(df.set_index('id')==0).all(1).values]
```

Output:

```
   id  m1  m2  m3
0  111  20   0  12
2  333   3   1  18
```

Answer (score 4):

```
In [91]: ndf = df[df.filter(regex='^m').astype(bool).any(1)]

In [92]: ndf
Out[92]:
    id  m1  m2  m3
0  111  20   0  12
2  333   3   1  18
```

Comment: whats `^m` I'm new to that pattern?

Comment: Very smart, took me a sec to figure out astyp(bool) here :)

Comment: @Bharathshetty, it's a RegEx - meaning string that starts with `"m"`

Comment: Oh shit I imagined an escape character behind `m` I thought its like `^\m`. My bad I feel stupid now haha

Answer (score 0):

here,it can be done in simple way as follows.

`df=df[df['id']!=222]`

`print(df)`

`id  m1  m2  m3
0  111  20   0  12
2  333   3   1  18`